# Solving heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series, heat-equation

Given $k>0$ and $u_0\in\mathcal{C}^1[0,L]$, $u_0\geq 0$ we have the problem
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x,t)=k\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2},&0<x<L,&t>0\\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(0,t)=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(L,t)=0,&t>0\\
u(x,0)=u_0(x),&0\leq x\leq L
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Spliting variables I get the solution
$$u(x,t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\cos{(\frac{n\pi x}{L})}e^{-(\frac{n\pi}{L})^2kt}$$
where
$$a_n=\frac{2}{L}\int_0^Lu_0(s)\cos(\frac{n\pi s}{L})ds$$
after that I want to show that this series converges and also that this is actually a classical solution of the problem, there is where I am stuck.

Comment: The solution you wrote corresponds to Dirichlet boundary conditions ($u(0,t)=u(0,L)=0$), but you have Neumann boundary conditions.

Comment: You are right, I think it is fixed now.

Comment: What do you mean by "a classical solution" ?

Comment: I think that terminology is used in oposition to distributional solution (I am introducing myself into PDE so better confirm that somewhere else). So it would be just a $\mathcal{C^2}$ function satisfying the equation and the boundary conditions.

Comment: Now that I think about it, showing that the series absolutely converges is enough to show that $u$ is a classical solution, because then you can exchange derivatives with the sum, right?